# Changing key pair name of an EC2 after modifying authorized_keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance managed by Elastic Beanstalk, and I recently changed my key pair to a new one (`findy-key-2`) by modifying `authorized_keys`, because I lost my old private key (`findy-key`).

```
$ cat authorized_keys
ssh-rsa [my private key] findy-key-2
```

So right now I have ssh access to my own instance.

However, perhaps because I changed the key pair manually, it seems that EC2 doesn't recognize the new key pair name correctly. In the EC2 console, it still says the key pair name is `findy-key`, which I already deleted.

And because of that, I'm getting the error below when trying to upgrade to Amazon Linux 2 on the EB dashboard.

```
Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'findy-key' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'EC2KeyName'): The key pair 'findy-key' does not exist
```

I noticed that under Elastic Beanstalk Dashboard > Configuration > Security, I can choose the new key from the EC2 key pair drop-down. But the warning message, `Each of your existing EC2 instances will be replaced and your new settings will take effect then.` implying that my current instance will be terminated, is frightening me because there *might* be some side effects such as loosing connection to my RDS volume (yes, I'm a newbie to AWS).

Hence, I'm trying to find a way to change the key pair name of an EC2 instance without terminating and creating a new one. If that's not possible, I want to know what are the possible side effects of replacing an EC2 instance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For short term solution, you can use [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) to login to your instances. For this you will need to add [SSM permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-instance-profile.html) to your EB instance profile/role.

You can also try using [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html) which may work out of the box on the instances and you don't have to do anything special to use it.

But for the **long term solution**, you have to use EB options for that. The reason is that you instances run in Autoscaling group and they can be terminated at any time anyway. So if you are worrying about "some side effects", they you have to **redesign** your application so that it is **stateless**. This means that your application does not depend on any instance terminations and re-launch due to autoscaling events.

Comment: What is the point of using SSM or EC2 Instance Connect when I already have ssh access to the instance? What do I need to do after sshing into the instance?

Comment: @shinhong There are many benefits of SSM. One of them is that you don't have to worry about any ssh keys, and you control access to the instance using IAM.

Comment: I mean, my main problem is that I'm getting `key-pair does not exist` error when trying to upgrade from Amazon Linux to Amazon Linux 2. I am wondering how to solve this issue once I sshed into the instance. I guess the question was not clear enough :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating another private key named `findy-key` (which is the name of the old key I deleted before) in AWS Console, and adding its public key in `authorized_keys`.